# Use NSTask to ssh into another computer

Tags: cocoa, ssh, nstask

Is there a way I can use NSTask to ssh into another computer (in this case a chumby) and run commands on that device?  I also have a password on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at LibSSH2: http://www.libssh2.org/